# How to deploy a smart contract on the mainnet?

Tags: smart-contract, mainnet, eosio.system, contract-development, mainchain

I created and tested my smart contract on testnet.
Now I want to deploy it on mainnet, I assume I have to purchase some EOS token and buy ram, cpu and net... I can't find anything in the docs about the process. So the question is how can I deploy my smart contract on mainnet?

I could not find any information even about the API endpoint of the mainnet.

I'm hoping you had a similar experience and can provide me with any helpful info.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following API:

https://mainnet.eosn.io

You'll need to:

- Create account (if you have an existing account can use https://bloks.io/wallet/create-account).
- Get a free power up for CPU/NET https://eospowerup.io/free
- Buy RAM for the contract
- To get more CPU/NET use the power up https://bloks.io/wallet/powerup, perhaps 10k for CPU and 1k for NET
- Use cleos to deploy the contract `cleos -u url set contract` or you can deploy from a frontend here https://bloks.io/wallet/utilities/upload-contract (you'll need to login with your account).  You can also login to bloks using the cleos option which will populate the cleos commands for you.

Cleos docs:
https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/cleos/command-reference/set/set-contract

More APIs here:
https://validate.eosnation.io/eos/reports/api_versions.html

Account creation guide: https://www.eosx.io/guides/how-to-create-account